# pass an object to a user controls ViewModel in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a View that uses a specific ViewModel.

The viewModel has various object e.g. Foo, Bar...etc

I have a user control that has its own ViewModel which contains a Foo object.

How do pass the Foo object from the page View to the usercontrols ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("partial", Model.Foo); %>
```

Then one of two things will happen.

1. *If the View's `Model.Foo` is **non**-null*, then the UserControl's `Model` will be equal to the View's `Model.Foo`, and the UserControl's `Model.Foo` will be the View's `Model.Foo.Foo`.
2. *If the View's `Model.Foo` is **null**, then the UserControl's `Model` will be equal to the View's `Model`, and the UserControl's `Model.Foo` will be the View's `Model.Foo`. If the View's `Model` and `Model.Foo` are not the same type and the View's `Model` is non-null and if the UserControl uses strongly typed view data, then you will get a runtime error since the UserControl's model is now of type `TViewModel` instead of `TUserControlModel`.

Comment: i got it working by having Foo as a parameter in the constructor of the usercontrol view model. then passing the instance of the usercontrol viewmodel as the second parameter  in the renderpartial method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("partial", Model.Foo); %>
```

Comment: is the user control clever enough to make its own Foo object equal to the one passed here? the View and the user control have different ViewModels which both contain a Foo